# Configure HSQLDB datasource with Thorntail / Wildfly Swarm

Tags: wildfly, hsqldb, thorntail

I have a problem with thorntail / wildfly.

I am trying to declare hsql driver and i don't success.

Thorntail says me:
2022-08-24 15:48:08,912 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 35) WFLYCTL0013: L'op�ration ("add") a �chou� - adresse : ([
("subsystem" => "datasources"),
("jdbc-driver" => "org.hsqldb")

I guess I put wrong values in datasources / jdbc-drivers.

But what are the right values ?

Here's the extract of configuration:

```
swarm:
  logging: INFO
  http:
     port: 8080

  datasources:
    jdbc-drivers:
      org.hsqldb:
        driver-class-name: org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
        xa-datasource-class-name: org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXADataSource
        driver-module-name: org.hsqdb
```

Thanks,

Stéphne

Comment: I add that i insert the right dependancy in the pom.xml file:
```
    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
     <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
     <version>2.7.0</version>
  
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thorntail has reached its end of life more than 2 years ago. It is no longer supported. I suggest you migrate to Quarkus or WildFly.

Comment: Yes i will but for now it's impossible.
Any help is welcome !
Stéphane

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution...
Th proble mwas that i had a diffrence between the file module.xml and the driver-module-name attribute like this: one character was missing.

module.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.hsqldb">

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="hsqldb-2.7.0.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

And :

```
swarm:
  logging: INFO
  http:
     port: 8080

  datasources:
    jdbc-drivers:
      org.hsqldb:
        driver-class-name: org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
        xa-datasource-class-name: org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXADataSource
        driver-module-name: org.hsqdb
```

That was all.... ;-)

Stéphane